# Seeking guidance on predicting salinity of River network with incomplete data

Tags: models, rivers, salinity

So I am working with the USGS data on salinity of various River reaches in the United States and not every reach mapped has been tested. Is there an accepted model for inferring the salinity of reaches given that you only have data of portions of the network? What is the information I would need for a such predictions?

Edit:

Let me rephrase. Imagine a table with the following information:

Column 1: a complete set of reach codes for the River network.
Column 2: the reach directly upstream from the reach in column 1
Column 3: the main reach the reaches in columns 1 and 2 all flow back into—a main reach being defined as a reach that empties into an ocean/lake/other terminal body of water
Column 4: the mean salinity of each reach in column 1 for a period of time with null Values for many reaches that do not have any observations.
Column 5: the time span for the date available in column 4

Now given these criteria, do I have enough to make estimates for the information in column 4 given if my goal is to be accurate enough to classify the river as fresh, brackish, saline? If not, what other data would be useful to arrive at a reasonable set of estimates?